# What is ResourceId Here?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Currently, am trying to get the bearer token from the AAD(which is a Native app). I have the current block of code

```
private AuthenticationContext authContext = null;
    authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientId, redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always))
```

So in the current Code block what is **todoListResourceId** ?

Answer (score 0):

That's the resource identifier for the API you want an access token for.
In this case your client app says to Azure AD "Give me a token for the Todo List Service".

In case of MS APIs, you typically use the URI e.g.:

- MS Graph API: `https://graph.microsoft.com`
- Azure AD Graph API: `https://graph.windows.net`

In case of your own APIs, you can use either the API client id or App ID URI (found in the Properties for the app registration).
Though it does require the API to be configured to accept both as a valid audience.
If it only accepts one, then you have to use that one.

Comment: With the same we tried, actually our target is to deal with https://graph.microsoft.com, but it gives no token found.

Comment: Does it prompt you for authentication?

Comment: Yes, with alot of struggle

Comment: @juunas Can i get access token for both Todo List Service and https://graph.windows.net by making a single call.

Comment: No. You need two calls.